# Slow Query with Limit and HashAggregates

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

Postgres 9.3

In the following example query, why does the HashAggregate process 10 million rows (in 5s) instead of stopping as soon as it has collected 1 row as specified by the limit (which should take less than 1ms)?

I have problems like that with many limited queries... the HashAggregate makes limited queries take *as long as* unlimited queries... which makes the limit totally useless.

Is there a reason why it cannot stop after having collected n rows?

Create some test data:

```
create table foo (x integer);
insert into foo (x) (select * from generate_series(1, 10000000));
```

Run the query:

```
explain analyze
select x from foo group by x limit 1;
```

or with distinct instead of group by (results in the same query plan!):

```
explain analyze
select distinct x from foo limit 1;
```

http://explain.depesz.com/s/arPX

```
 Limit  (cost=176992.00..176992.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=5185.125..5185.125 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=176992.00..176994.00 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=5185.124..5185.124 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..150443.20 rows=10619520 width=4) (actual time=0.018..949.926 rows=10000000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 5244.966 ms
```

Comment: the `rows=200` part is just an estimate from a table that hasn't be analyzed.

Comment: Your example hardly makes sense. Can be simplified to `select x from foo limit 1;` And Postgres stops after collecting *1* row for this. Maybe you can provide a test case with the real problem (if there is one)?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter replace "group by" with "distinct".. that results in exactly the same query plan. why does it have to take 5s to find the first distinct row? does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a query with an "order by", "distinct", or aggregate function, the entire query results have to be gathered, sorted, and aggregated before a limit can be applied (regardless of the limit number). You can rewrite the query in a number of ways to achieve the same result, but faster, however, I'd need to see a more lifelike query as the example isn't very realistic of an actual use case.

When considering your example, consider how the DB would determine which result to show (limit 1).. it has to perform some kind of  a sort. I'm assuming that your actual examples would include a limit > 1, but i they are using limit 1, then there are many ways to rewrite the queries to take advantage of their limited rows.

Comment: Why does distinct have to gather the entire query results when it should only return n distinct values? The first two distinct values of 3, 3, 1, 2, 3,... are 3 and 1 (its enough to look at the first three values). "It has to perform some kind of sort" - nope. There's clearly no sort happening in the query plan I posted.. HashAggregates don't need that.

Comment: @stmax Imagine your query was limit 1000000000 instead of 1. First, it would have to get all the distinct values (which involves going through every single row to find the distinct values), then it limits those values. This issue shows up, not only in distinct queries, group by queries, but also in queries that contain functions (select some_expensive_function(x) from y limit 1). I actually submitted a request to the hackers group to optimize these types of issues, however, it apparently breaks common sql convention and may have side effects, so it was declined.

Comment: could you post a link that explains what "common sql convention" this would break? thanks

Comment: Tom Lane, in this thread http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Feature-request-optimizer-improvement-td5776581.html says it breaks the SQL computational model, I don't have a link to the source.

Comment: Interesting read, will have to think about it some more, thanks.